# DIV to trigger a Radio Button

Tags: html, triggers, click

I'm struggling to get my "event" div to trigger the allocated radio button.

```
<section class="main">
<ul class="timeline">

    <li class="event">
        <input type="radio" name="tl-group"/>
        <label></label>
        <div class="thumb user-3">title</div>

                    <div class="content-perspective">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="content-inner">
                                <h3>Title</h3>
                                                <p>TEXT</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </li>  

    <li class="event"> 
    ...
    </li> 

</ul>
```

I want `<div class="thumb user-3">title</div>` to work as a radio button as well. I want both to be clickable. I've tried different ideas but doesn't seems to work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the checked attribute of radio to value "checked" when clicked the div.

```
<div class="thumb user-3" onclick="document.getElementsByName('tl-group').checked='checked';">title</div>
```

Comment: :( doesn't work.... aaah... I've tried so many things and its just doesn't work....:(

Comment: sorry i forgot the [0], please try again: <div class="thumb user-3" onclick="document.getElementsByName('tl-group')[0].checked='checked';">title</div>

Answer (score 0):

I  have been searching for the same piece of code as well. It worked! Saved my day.

`div class="thumb user-3" onclick="document.getElementsByName('tl-group')[0].checked='‌​checked';"`

For those who are looking into refining the existing code by clicking barely anywhere (radio button, img div or ...the content-inner to trigger event), this is the code that works for me:

`div class="content-inner" onclick="document.getElementsByName('tl-group')[0].checked='checked';"`

Increase the [0] to 1,2,3, etc for more contents array.